# Made a commit on main, pulled, then pushed another branch that has same changes as this commit--do i need to do anything?

Tags: git, github

Here's what I did (mistake that caused the issue in **bold**):

1. On branch `update-1`
2. Pushed changes to `origin` and submitted as PR #1
3. Checked out `main`
4. Checked out new branch `update-2` to make a change "ABC"->"XYZ"
5. Saw that PR #1 had been approved
6. Checked out `main` so that I could pull PR #1 changes
7. **Forgot that I was in `main`, and committed "ABC"->"XYZ" change that was intended for branch `update-2`**
8. Pulled PR #1 into `main`, which merged it with the local "ABC"->"XYZ" commit
9. Checked out `update-2`
10. Made the "ABC"->"XYZ" change (again) and committed it to `update-2`
11. Pushed `update-2` commit to `origin` and submitted it as PR #2
12. Checked out `main`
13. Saw that `main` is 1 commit ahead of `origin`

Because `main` now already has the "ABC"->"XYZ" change (which, if I understand correctly, is why it's showing as 1 commit ahead of `origin`), I'm wondering if I need to do anything special to resolve this, or if it will naturally solve itself when I pull `origin` after PR #2 is approved.  When I try to revert `main` to its previous commit via `git revert HEAD~1`, I get:

```
error: commit fa939e7c532c32a7003b8ddfaf5af785289041df is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

I don't understand the `-m` option well enough to know whether I should use it in this situation.

What I'm hoping will happen is:

1. PR #2 gets approved and merged into `origin`
2. I pull `origin` into `main`
3. The "ABC"->"XYZ" change is already in `main`, so the file contents remain the same
4. `main` and `origin` are now up-to-date with each other

Is this what will happen, or do I need to do anything else to fix this before I pull `origin` into `main`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, I don't need to do anything.  I pulled and everything went fine, got the following message:

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```